# Issue with HTML-entities decoding

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-entities

I have a PHP server responding with strings via Ajax (json) response for example,

```
su&#0x146;iem
```

Where as the word sent from server is

> suņiem

[w3org Character ref chart](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

I'm having trouble displaying this in html. **From my research** it needs to be decoded from HTML-entities but I see that only those special characters cause trouble with are not on the [w3org](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) list.

I also have **tried** decoding from base64, it seems it is not base64 though, and Js functions of `decodeURIComponent(string);`

Maybe it's not html-entity and something else altogether.

Let me know what else you want to know.

Comment: Why JavaScript is related?

Comment: I'm getting the string in Json via Ajax request. I'll add that in question

Comment: Is expected result `’` character? That is `su’iem`?

Comment: It would work if the code was `&#x00146;`  How is it getting encoded, htmlentities() in php?

Comment: @siguza  &apos;  work as expected. but some characters like ņ cause this bug. such characters are not int w3org ref chart

Comment: @MahinKhan I just noticed that `&#...;` doesn't seem to work with (this) hex notation, even in pure HTML... retracted my close vote.

Comment: _"but some characters like ņ cause this bug"_ What do you mean? Is `"su&#0x146;iem"` or `"suņiem"` sent from server?

Comment: @guest271314 the expected character is `ņ`  as in `suņiem`

Comment: @Siguza That does not clarify what is sent from server, nor what expected result is. Is `"su&#0x146;iem"` or `"suņiem"` response from server?

Comment: @guest271314 sorry. I receive `su&#0x146;iem` in Ajax response. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @MahinKhan Why do you expect `"suņiem"` to be rendered at `html`?

Comment: @guest271314 yes, exactly!
I tried making a snippet with the question but my server wasn't accessible.

Comment: `&#146;` renders `’` character at `html`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144011/discussion-between-mahin-khan-and-guest271314).

Comment: Add the PHP code that generates this.

Comment: @chris85 I will, shortly.